# C++ error al hacer un input con cin o getline(std::cin, var) devuelve un bucle al escribir con espacios o un v

Tags: c++, c, while

Al pedir datos y colocar un espacio,al utilizar cin >> temp.nombre;, me da un error que provoca un bucle de los 2 while a la vez o, al utilizar getline(std:cin, temp.nombre);, me salta la pregunta. El codigo es el siguiente.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;


struct temporal {
    string nombre;
    long edad;
    int conf;
    int num;
    int num2;
    int num3;
    int num4;
    int num5;
    int num6;
    int num7;
    int num8;
};
temporal temp;


int opt;
int op;
int id;
string nombre[100];
long edad[100];
int nDatos=-1;
int actDatos = -1;
int insertOn;
int actB;
int inported;
int lines;



int main() {
            cout << "Cuantas personas queres agregar:  "; cin >> temp.num;
            actB = nDatos;
            temp.num2 = temp.num;
            while(temp.num >= 1){
                if(op == 1) {
                    cout << "Introduce un nombre:  ";
                      std::getline( std::cin, temp.nombre );//o al utilizar cin >> temp.nombre;
                    cout << "Introduce una edad:  "; 
                    cin >> temp.edad;
                    actDatos ++;
                    temp.num --;
                    nDatos = actDatos;
                    insertOn = nDatos;
                    nombre[insertOn] = temp.nombre;
                    edad[insertOn] = temp.edad;
                    clear();        
                }
            }
                clear();
                cout << "Has agregado a estas persona(s)" << endl;
                while(actB +1 <= nDatos){
                actB = actB + 1;
                cout << nombre[actB] << "          " << edad[actB] << endl;

                }
                op = 0;
        }
```

Comment: Creo que tu problema se podría resumir en un [mcve] menos extenso. También podrías pasarte por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), y de paso obtener tu primera medalla :-) Un saludo.

Comment: Vale lo he editado lo maximo que pude, el error es que si pongo getline me salta el cin del nombre y si pongo cin >> temp.nombre; si pongo un espacio me da un error que deriva en un bucle infinito

Answer (score 1):

Vale lo he resuelto, el error era tan simple como poner:

```
getline( cin.ignore(100, '\n'), temp.nombre);
```

Comment: agrega la explicacion de que hace esa linea , como esta formada la respuesta , es muy baja calidad

Comment: Por favor recuerda [aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.